# Url Rewriting with Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll

Tags: asp.net, url, rewriting

We are trying to rewrite like domainname.com/cityname. However this not resolving to the respective page. But when we try something like this domainname.com/city/cityname it works well and resolve to the correct/designated url

This is the code in webconfig

```
<rewriter>
<rewrite url="~/city/(.+)" to="~/Default.aspx?propid=$1" processing="stop"/>
</rewriter>
```

How to redirect to the page by giving domainname.com/cityname

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<rewriter>
<rewrite url="/(.+)" to="/Default.aspx?propid=$1" processing="stop"/>
</rewriter>
```

where $1 is the fraction after / in the url

so

```
something.com/name_of_city
```

will redirect to

```
something.com/Default.aspx?propid=name_of_city
```